# How to move specific pdf documents in a folder into a new folder? The documents I want to move all have a specific keyword in their name

Tags: powershell, windows-10

My computer is under strict administrative control and I can only use PowerShell. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) to enumerate the files in a folder based on a [wildcard filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1), and use [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-5.1) to move them to a new directory. Where `keyword` is the keyword:

```
Get-ChildItem -File C:\path\to\directory\*keyword*.pdf | ForEach-Object {
  Move-Item -Force $_ C:\path\to\new\directory
}
```

Or you can just use `Move-Item` directly, but note that this will also evaluate directories which might accidentally move files you don't want (for example, if you have a directory ending in `.pdf`, it might also move that entire directory):

```
Move-Item -Force C:\path\to\directory\*keyword*.pdf C:\path\to\new\directory
```